# Get as number for date

Tags: php, filemaker

I have a function GetAsNumber(date) in filemaker.
Ex: `GetAsNumber(10/10/2008) returns 733325.`
I need to write function GetAsNumber with PHP.But with function mktime() in php i can't do it the same filemaker.

Answer (score 1):

Odd function, but this appears to do the trick:

```
function getasnumber($date)
{
    $dt_date = new DateTime($date);
    $dt_start = new DateTime('1/0/0001');
    return $dt_date->diff($dt_start)->days;
}

var_dump(getasnumber('10/10/2008')); // 733325
var_dump(getasnumber('10/10/2014')); // 735516
```

The return values appear to be right according to the first date you supplied, and this [other documentation](http://www.filemaker.com/12help/html/func_ref3.33.56.html).

Answer (score 1):

This function seems to be replicating the same thing as the FileMaker's `GetAsNumber` function :

```
function GetAsNumber($str) {
    static $DATE_OFFSET = 719163;  // adjust because PHP is from 1980 and Filemaker from 0001
    static $SECONDS_IN_DAYS = 86400;  // get only days from date

    if (preg_match('/^(\\d{2})[-\\/\\.](\\d{2})[-\\/\\.](\\d{2}|\\d{4})$/', trim($str), $matches)) {
        $val = intval(strtotime("{$matches[1]}-{$matches[2]}-{$matches[3]}") / $SECONDS_IN_DAYS) + $DATE_OFFSET;
    } else {
        $val = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\\d\\.]/', '', $str));
    }

    return $val;
}
```

Tested with these values :

```
echo GetAsNumber("FY98") . ' == 98' . PHP_EOL;
echo GetAsNumber("$1,254.50") . ' == 1254.5' . PHP_EOL;
echo GetAsNumber("2 + 2") . ' == 22' . PHP_EOL;
echo GetAsNumber("TKV35FRG6HH84") . ' == 35684' . PHP_EOL;
echo GetAsNumber("10/10/2014") . ' == 735516' . PHP_EOL;
echo GetAsNumber("10/10/2008") . ' == 733325' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Yours is better. I had a brain fart and for some reason only did the date part, probably because it was such an odd return value compared to the rest.